# PostgreSQL Insert Row from 2 Queries where one value is derived from the other

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table, `Images` that I am using (with PostGIS) to compute overlapping polygons. The image below shows a super simple example.

[image]

The geometry results of this spatial query are being pushed into a `geom` column of an `overlay` table using the following query.

```
INSERT INTO overlay(geom)
(
    SELECT ST_AsEWKB(geom) AS geom FROM ST_Dump((
        SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
            SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
                SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_DUMP(footprint_latlon)).geom) AS the_geom
                FROM images AS lines
        ) AS noded_lines
    ))
)
```

Then I run a second query to compute the `Images` polygons that have contributed to the overlay. These are the letters in the image and the results populate an array in the `Overlay` table. Specifically,

```
UPDATE overlay
SET intersections = imgs.iid
FROM (
        SELECT array_agg(images.id)
        FROM overlay, images
        ST_INTERSECTS(overlay.geom, images.footprint_latlon)
        GROUP BY overlay.id
    ) AS intersections
WHERE imgs.id = overlay.id;
```

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to do this in one pass. That is, compute the intersecting geom from the `Images` table, perform the `ST_INTERSECTS` check with the result from the previous, and *then* enter the row. This would take the two pass approach to a one pass approach.

So far, I have tried variations on the following to no avail. Any suggestions or documentation links that might push me in the right directions appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO overlay(geom,intersections)
(SELECT ST_AsEWKB(geom) FROM ST_Dump((
        SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
            SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
                SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_DUMP(footprint_latlon)).geom) FROM images) AS the_geom)
     as geom)),
 (SELECT array_agg(images.id)
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geom, images.footprint_latlon) AS iid);
```

Comment: You mean insert in one pass? With no need to update? Maybe you need CTE?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Comment: @Jervs Yes. Insert in one pass without the need for an update. Thanks you for the link to CTE. I will check that out now.